# Meaning of git statement

Tags: git, requirements

I was wondering about a git statement which I found in the `requirements.txt` file of one of my projects.

`-e git+https://github.com/facebookresearch/densepose@35e69d110b432704c2183cd6aea531f4f695edbe#egg=Detectron`

I don't really understand where this statement is pointing to.

Can someone please explain this to me?

Comment: You mean where in the sense of which specific Git commit, or do you want to know about pip requirement formats?

Comment: @slhck I want to specifically know the meaning of the portion after the `@` symbol. `35e69d110b432704c2183cd6aea531f4f695edbe#egg=Detectron` this part.

Comment: This isn’t about Git. It’s about [requirements.txt](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/user_guide/#requirements-files).

Answer (score 1):

This is [pip-specific syntax](https://pip.readthedocs.io/en/1.1/requirements.html#git) for "editable" dependencies; it is not understood by git itself.

- `@hash` lets you select a specific Git commit (similar to `@rev` in SVN URLs).
- `#egg=name` lets you specify the project name that would otherwise be in requirements.txt (e.g. if a normal dependency was like `MyProject==3.0` then the URL would need to have `#egg=MyProject`).